# Scraping specific elements from a div

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to retrieve these elements from this page:

[image: Whoscored]

Consider I'm using selenium webdriver and XPath for Python.

That particular div (the dark one) is referrend in xpath as:

```
//*[@id="stadium"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[9]
```

So my code is:

```
playID =[]
dtype = []
events = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="stadium"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[9]')

for a in events:
    dtype.append(a.get_attribute('data-type'))
    playID.append(a.get_attribute('data-player-id'))
print(playID)
print(dtype)
```

but it seems, It retrieves data only from the dark div and not from the children.

How could I modify my XPath expression in order to get all interesting data (those red highlighted in the picture)? Consider some divs have a number of children while others could have more or less so it won't help specify the inner div as another page could miss them and in general I can't know how many inner divs are in a specific one (like the dark one). I hope to have clearly explained myself. :)

Sorry for my bad English and please consider I'm not a developer, it's just for fun so forgive the bad coding. :)

I guess I've searched for this answer but I haven't found anything clear enough to apply to my problem.

Comment: Are you looking for the `data-type` attribute for DIVs that are only under the man of the match or ? Your intent isn't clear. This is clearly a stats page and I'm assuming public, a link to the page would help a lot also.

Answer (score 0):

It not usually a good idea to have such an specific query (`'//*[@id="stadium"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[9]'`). If the class "player-key-incidents" is unique, this should work:

```
events = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="player-key-incidents"]/div')
```

You can do something similar using CSS selectors:

```
events = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.player-key-incidents > div")
```

These two commands are finding the children of the div with the class "player-key-incidents".

Comment: Thanks @Fernando, actually your proposal gathers all the events in the page and not in that particular Node. Unfortunatelly is not unique. Anyway I guess I've found a solution as follows: 'code' div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="stadium"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[11]')
events = div.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*') 'code' and then managing the obtained list.